# How to link javascript file to an id

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript code called static.js, this works great on its own when it is sourced in the html file as such:

```
<script src="./static.js"></script>
```

The code executes and you can see it on the screen, however I would like add effects on to this output. How can I associate an entire javascript file to a `<canvas>` or an id. So that I put it between `<div>` and layer effects on top of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [this article](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp), It seems that you would create the  tag in your index.html file, and the you would be able to control it in the JavaScript file like so, assuming that the id of the canvas element is "myCanvas":

```
var canvasVariable = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
```

And then you would be able to add effects to that canvas by using methods like:

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.moveTo(0,0);
ctx.lineTo(200,100);
ctx.stroke();
```

[This example](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_canvas_tut_path) is from the aforementioned article and creates a diagonal line across the canvas.

Also, for future reference, mention that you are using jquery. Thankfully I recognized the error and imported it.

I hope this was able to help!

phylo